# DimensionAttributeSetStorage by DefaultDimension

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

i need to create **DimensionAttributeSetStorage** items by **DefaultDimension** field (**CustTable.DefaultDimension** for example).
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

On the form use [`DimensionDefaultingController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dimensiondefaultingcontroller.aspx).

Also see *Implementing the Account and Financial Dimensions Framework AX2012* White Paper (http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/3/4E36B655-568E-4D4A-B161-152B28BAAF30/Implementing_the_Account_and_Financial_Dimensions_Framework_AX2012.pdf).

---

If you need to create default dimension from the code you can use the [`DMFDimensionHelper::generateDefaultDimension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dmfdimensionhelper.generatedefaultdimension.aspx) method.

Sample:

```cs
DMFDataSourceProperties sourceProperties;
sourceProperties.ChartOfAccountsDelimiter = DimensionLedgerAccountDelimiter::Hyphen;
sourceProperties.DimensionAttribute = "Dim1-Dim2"; // dimension codes

x.DefaultDimension = DMFDimensionHelper::generateDefaultDimension("001-ABC", sourceProperties, "");
```

Comment: This sample code relies on the data migration framework, which isn't the same or installed in all versions of AX...for anyone who may stumble upon it.